# How to read content of all files in 1 directory

Tags: node.js, fs

So I tried to do it but I can not get it working.
In each file is random number like this "12" and I need to check all files and choose the one which have the highest number and get the file name of that file in variable.

This is what I have tried so far

```
function readFiles(dirname, onFileContent, onError) {
  fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, filenames) {
    if (err) {
      onError(err);
      return;
    }
    filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
      fs.readFile(dirname + filename, "utf-8", function(err, content) {
        if (err) {
          onError(err);
          return;
        }
        onFileContent(filename, content);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Thank you guys for any response.

Comment: Welcoem to Stack Overflow! Please, when asking a question try to be as specific as possible and provide at least parts of your code. What do you mean each file has a number? how?

Comment: In each file is random number and I need to get file which has the highest number.

Comment: How is the number stored in the file? What have you tried?

Comment: function readFiles(dirname, onFileContent, onError) {
  fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, filenames) {
    if (err) {
      onError(err);
      return;
    }
    filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
      fs.readFile(dirname + filename, 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
        if (err) {
          onError(err);
          return;
        }
        onFileContent(filename, content);
      });
    });
  });
}

Comment: @NotBad edit your answer and add the appropriate info/code there, don't paste it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Returns filename of file containing the largest integer within a specified directory */
const getFileWithLargestInteger = (pathToFolder) => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(pathToFolder);
  const content = files.map(f => +fs.readFileSync(`${pathToFolder}/${f}`, 'UTF-8'));
  const largestInteger = Math.max(...content);
  const fileWithLargestInteger = files[content.indexOf(largestInteger)];

  return fileWithLargestInteger;
}
```

Comment: When I try to log it to console I get undefined   console.log(fileWithLargestInteger);

Comment: You cannot access a variable outside of its scope. You need to do `console.log(getFileWithLargestInteger('<Path to folder here>'));`

Answer (score 0):

What if there is two files with same number?

```
const getSecondFileName = (pathToFolder) => {
      const files = fs.readdirSync(pathToFolder);
      const content = files.map(f => +fs.readFileSync(`${pathToFolder}/${f}`, 'UTF-8'));
      const arrayCopy = [...content];
      const secondLargestNum = arrayCopy.sort()[arrayCopy.length - 2]
      const secondFileWithLargestInteger = files[content.indexOf(secondLargestNum)];

      return secondFileWithLargestInteger;        
    }
```